# When someone introduce you to another person by email and "ends" his communication with you, should I reply just to that person or to both?

Tags: email

Context: I've been talking by email with a recruiting person and we have had an interview for a position. After this he requested me to send him my resume so he can send it to a team. I did and now he sends me this:

> Hi rewobs,
>
> I would like to introduce you to Batman. Batman is the recruiter in
> your town, who will now take you through the process regarding the
> position we spoke about.
>
> It's been a pleasure talking to you and keep in touch.
>
> Thanks,
> Chuck Norris.

**I want to reply Chuck Norris to thank him:** **Should I include Batman in CC or just Chuck Norris?**

Additionally, should I email Batman or wait him to email me?

Comment: I want to work where you work. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general rule is to only CC people if you think they should have the information in the conversation. Since you have something to say to each of them, I think it's entirely appropriate to reply-all here.

> Chuck, thanks for your help. It's been a pleasure working with you and round-housing bad guys.
>
> Bruce, let me know if you need any more information from me. Maybe we can set up a time for me to swing by the batcave and talk further.

Or whatever it is you want to say. If you intend the message to be much longer, (a lengthy heartfelt thank you letter or full narrative history of all of your past jobs) then it would be better to split into two emails. You just don't want to barrage people with information they don't need.

Comment: I've edited a bit the answer to be clearer. I want to reply to Chuck Norris for give thanks for everything, wouldn't it be rude not to?

Comment: @rewobs Yes, that does change things a bit. I will update my answer.